# How to treat unspecified $f(x)$ in non-homogenous ODE $u'+u=f$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I remember that if the R.H.S. of a non-homogenous ODE is some known function, then one can find its particular solution

By recalling some examples I think the $f$ causes some convolution term to the solution, but I cannot find a general reference for this.

Comment: $f(x)=e^{-x}\int_{x_0}^x e^tf(t)\,dt$ works as a special solution.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yeah but I'm trying to recall, how to deduce that.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Use the integrating factor $e^x$.

Solution:

> $(u e^x)' = u'e^x + ue^x= f e^x$